# Python: verify if elements of list exist in file and print if they dont

Tags: python

I have list which is output of a function, I want to verify if elements of array are in the file (text file containing server names) and I want to print only those servers which are not in the file.

Thinking of something on these lines:

```
host_list = ['abc.server.com', 'xyz.server.com']
sfile = open("slist.txt","r")
for num in host_list:
        do 
           for  aline in sfile.realines():
                if num =! aline.split()
                print num
sfile.close()
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: `do` is not valid python syntax. You also want `!=` as opposed to `=!`. And use a `with` block to open files.

Comment: you have several typos in your code, actually.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking, dint actually test, your comments were helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do what you are trying to do:

```
host_list = ['abc.server.com', 'xyz.server.com']
sfile = open("slist.txt","r")
hosts_in_file = set()
for line in sfile:
  for server in line.strip().split():
    hosts_in_file.add(server)

print [host  for host in host_list if host not in hosts_in_file]
sfile.close()
```